# Microsoft Edge browser embed audio shows buzz icon

Tags: javascript, asp.net, microsoft-edge

I use this function for play sound

```
var soundObject = null;
function PlaySound() {

    if (soundObject != null) {
        document.body.removeChild(soundObject);
        soundObject.removed = true;
        soundObject = null;
    }
    soundObject = document.createElement("embed");
    //soundObject.setAttribute("src", "../Sounds/beep-01a1.wav");
    soundObject.setAttribute("src", "../Sounds/Small Blink.mp3");

    soundObject.setAttribute("hidden", true);
    soundObject.setAttribute("autostart", true);
    document.body.appendChild(soundObject);
    // alert('hii sound');
}
```

it works fine in all browser instead of Microsoft Edge browser it shows buzzer icon in browser [image]

Any help is appreciable, Thanks.

Comment: What is a "buzzer icon"?

Comment: @connum thanks for response it plays the sound but the above img of buzzer shows on page bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Edge browser seemingly ignores the "hidden" attribute. Try this:

```
soundObject.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
```

Comment: Thanks buddy got the way :)